# Adding types to JS npm package

Tags: typescript, npm-package

I have built a JS package and now i want to add compatibility for typescript. I could not really get it to work by reading the TS docs on how to publish a npm package.

using

```
import { ClientConfigurationOptions } from "my-package";
```

is not working.

This is my package's structure:
[image]

and this is my `package.json` file

```json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "description here",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [
    "package-name"
  ],
  "author": "iKingNinja",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7"
  },
  "types": "types/index.d.ts"
}
```

and this is `package/types/index.d.ts`

```
export interface ClientConfigurationOptions {
    property1: string,
    property2: number
}
```

Why do i get the following error?

```
Module '"my-package"' has no exported member 'ClientConfigurationOptions'.
```

Comment: First, have you considered rewriting your project in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your module in type declaration files for a module:

```
declare module "my-package" {
  export interface ClientConfigurationOptions {
    property1: string,
    property2: number
  }
}
```

See [ambient modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) in the handbook.